# Send sqlite database in android email

Tags: android, sqlite, email

I am developing an application that tries to send an email database. But if the file axexo mail is sent. If Annex is not sent. The code is as follows:

```
public class Enviaremail extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                 
        MailSender mailsender = new MailSender("lalala@gmail.com", "xxxxxx");
        String[] toArr = { "lalala@gmail.com"};
        mailsender.set_to(toArr);
        mailsender.set_from("lalala@gmail.com");
        mailsender.set_subject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device.");
        mailsender.setBody("Gracias a Dios.");

        try {
           mailsender.addAttachment("/data/data/org.segure.sms/databases/agenda.db");               ;

            if (mailsender.send()) {
                Toast.makeText(Enviaremail.this,
                        "Email enviado exitosamente.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Enviaremail.this, "Email no fue enviado.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
        }


}
}
```

When I delete the line: mailsender.addAttachment("/data/data/org.segure.sms/databases/agenda.db") works and mail is sent. If I place it does not work. The file exists in the specified location. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know which mail sender lib are you using, but there are some ideas which may help: 1) check if the file is not open by your app 2) the folder you used is not public, try to copy it to your sd card or some publicly readable place before sending it.

Comment: The database is created by the application and is closed. I even tried to attach other files such as images and does not work. database is locked at the time of shipping.